# What happenes with my javascript code, it doesn't go with flow

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
var f1 = function () {
  console.log('f1');
};

var f2 = function (callback) {
  console.log('f2');
  return callback;
};

var f3 = function (callback) {
  console.log('f3');
  callback();
};

f3(f2(f1));
```

I want to write a program which prints f3 f2 f1. But I can't understand the result. I used Chrome debug and chose the line `f3(f2(f1));` is the break point. And it made me surprised that it started with f2 first. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: So you should reverse nested. Use `f1(f2(f3()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function `f3(...)`, you will need to resolve the arguments you need to parse. Hence, `f2(f1)` will be called first.

Now in `f2` you log before returning the callback. Hence log start with `f2`.

---

If you want the output to start with `f3`, you will need to pass reference of function instead of function call and call it inside `f3`.

Following is a sample for it:

```js
var f1 = function () {
  console.log('f1');
};

var f2 = function (callback) {
  console.log('f2');
  return callback();
};

var f3 = function (callback) {
  console.log('f3');
  callback();
};

f3(f2.bind(null, f1));
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will execute `f3`, but you pass a parameter to `f3`.
So `f2` will execute and print `f2`.
`f2` return callback to `f3` as a parameter, so `f3` execute to print `f3` and execute callback(`f1`).
Finally `f1` execute to print `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

f3(f2(f1))

Before running function f3, first f3 will get the arguments, since the argument is function call(f2(f1)), it has to be executed to continue the execution of the function, that is calling f2(f1):

f1 is just callback not a function call, so it will not be executed

f2 will log('f2') and return f1 as callback (without calling it)

f3 will get results (f1 as callback), f3 it will execute log('f3') and then call the function f1 (the returned callback) which log('f1').